# How to create multiple class objects with a loop in python?

Tags: python, class, object

Suppose you have to create 10 class objects in python, and do something with them, like:

```
obj_1 = MyClass()
other_object.add(obj_1)
obj_2 = MyClass()
other_object.add(obj_2)
.
.
.
obj_10 = MyClass()
other_object.add(obj_10)
```

How would you do it with a loop, and assign a variable to each object (like `obj_1`), so that the code will be shorter? Each object should be accessible outside the loop

```
obj_1.do_sth()
```

Comment: Obligatory pointer: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This question is asked every day in some variation. The answer is: keep your data out of your variable names, and [this is the obligatory blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

In this case, why not make a list of objs?

```
objs = [MyClass() for i in range(10)]
for obj in objs:
    other_object.add(obj)

objs[0].do_sth()
```

Comment: What if I want to assign generic variable names? like "obj_%s" %s

Comment: Then use a dictionary instead of a list. Your data has some structure (e.g., you have keys relating to values, or just a list of values, etc) and the Python data structures you choose should reflect that.

Answer (score 20):

you can use list to define it.

```
objs = list()
for i in range(10):
    objs.append(MyClass())
```

Comment: What if the number of classes is nuknown?

Comment: Since you're creating a list of objects you must know the number of objects your list must have, I guess you can always replace the number with a variable.

Comment: and if you're creating an object based on a conditions, you can use a while loop, where if the condition is true an object will be appended, to the list.

Answer (score 18):

Creating a dictionary as it has mentioned, but in this case each key has the name of the object name that you want to create. Then the value is set as the class you want to instantiate, see for example:

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.checkme = 'awesome {}'.format(self.name)
...

instanceNames = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

# Here you use the dictionary
holder = {name: MyClass(name=name) for name in instanceNames}
```

Then you just call the holder key and you will have all the properties and methods of your class available for you.

```
holder['red'].checkme
```

output:

```
'awesome red'
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a dictionary for unique names without a name list:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pretty_print_name()

    def pretty_print_name(self):
    print("This object's name is {}.".format(self.name))

my_objects = {}
for i in range(1,11):
    name = 'obj_{}'.format(i)
    my_objects[name] = my_objects.get(name, MyClass(name = name))
```

Output:

```
"This object's name is obj_1."
"This object's name is obj_2."
"This object's name is obj_3."
"This object's name is obj_4."
"This object's name is obj_5."
"This object's name is obj_6."
"This object's name is obj_7."
"This object's name is obj_8."
"This object's name is obj_9."
"This object's name is obj_10."
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
class Try:
    def do_somthing(self):
        print 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_list = []
    for obj in range(10):
        obj = Try()
        obj_list.append(obj)

    obj_list[0].do_somthing()
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: but I can't access the objects outside the loop that way

Comment: Yes i get your point.
I have updated my example please see that. 
Here I have appended the objects in a list and then you can use the object outside the loop any were.
Sorry but my solution is no different then others.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps to create several instances of a class using a `for` loop as well as the `globals()` function.

```
class Cir:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

This code defines a class called `Cir` with an `__init__` method that takes a single argument name and assigns it to the object's `name` attribute.

```
for i in range(5):
    inst_name = "my_instance_" + str(i)
    globals()[inst_name] = Cir(inst_name)
```

This loop creates five instances of the `Cir` class and assigns them to global variables with names that depend on the value of the loop variable `i`. The variable `inst_name` is created as a string that adds the constant string `my_instance_` with the string representation of the loop variable `i`. Then, the `globals()` function returns a dictionary of the global symbol table, and the resulting dictionary is accessed using `inst_name` as a key to add a new global variable with the name specified in `inst_name` and the value of the newly created instance of the `Cir` class with the name attribute set to `inst_name`.

```
print(my_instance_3.name)
```

This line of code prints the name attribute of the `my_instance_3` and ensures that the instances were created properly.