# Python: how to automatically create instance object?

Tags: python, class, object

I want to create instance objects automatically as I explained in the following:

```
Class MyClass:
     def __init__(self,x):
           self.x = x

list  = ["A","B"]
```

I want to create the following but automatically, means to loop through the list and create identical object for each element:

```
A = MyClass(text)
B = MyClass(text)
```

e.g. like the following which doesn't work:

```
# this doesn't work but explains more what I need
for i in list:
    i = MyClass(text)
```

Thanks to all of your help!

Comment: Could you clarify the exact output you hope to acheive? Because the following might be what you're looking for: `[ MyClass( text ) for _ in list ]` or something along those lines.

Comment: Similar to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598872/how-to-create-multiple-class-objects-with-a-loop-in-python/21599140#21599140

Comment: @sean I will provide a senario, lets say the input is unexpected employees' names and for each employees I require to process the data. so for each employee I must create a class.

Comment: @Tanveer that answer you provided will create something like this in a list <__main__.getchild instance at 0x97b1cac> while I expect it to be each A or B that can be played around easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can't and shouldn't shove things into your namespace like that. It's better to store those instances in a `dict` or a `list`

```
Class MyClass:
     def __init__(self,x):
           self.x = x

lst  = ["A","B"]  # don't use list as an identifier

myclasses = {k: MyClass(text) for k in lst}
```

Now your instances are

`myclasses['A']`, `myclasses['B']` etc.

If you really want to create a handful of variables in your namespace:

```
A, B = (MyClass(text) for x in range(2))
```

note that this means you need to be explicit. You can't get the A,B from a file or user input etc.

Don't be tempted to use `exec` to pull this off. It's probably the wrong way to go about solving your problem. Tell us *why* you think you need to do it instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer. your answer doesn't look to be working but I can also tell you why I need that and I got interested that such idea doesn't seem to be correct by experienced programmers like all of you who answered means there is another way to solve such problem and I am going to tell the problem. so what I am trying to do is to input unexpected information like "employee names" and for each one of them i need to do some analysis which requires me to create class for each one of them that is why I need to create class objects automatically as I don't expect fixed input names.

Comment: @jesy2013, that's precisely why you shouldn't store them in your local namespace. If a name conflicts with a keyword or a builtin or something else in your namespace, you will get interesting bugs. Most likely you should be using a dict with the keys being the employee names.

Comment: thanks then how do you suggest me to use dict in such case? if the input is only employee names then what and how should I assign keys for each employees?

Comment: @jesy2013, If the employee names are unique, you could just use them as the dictionary keys. Alternatively you can use a list and append each instance to that assuming that the employee name is store in the instance.