# create multiple objects of a class with different arguments

Tags: python

I know how to create multiple objects of the same class using a loop, similar to this 
[How to create multiple class objects with a loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598872/how-to-create-multiple-class-objects-with-a-loop-in-python)
However, what I want is different because each object has to be initialised with different arguments
my program now reads all the information (the arguments) from a file and store them in a python dictionary, like this:

```
objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John',13]}
```

and because the number of the objects which are needed depend on the information found on the file ..
I want to know if there's a way to automatically create (maybe by using a loop !) multiple class objects and initialised them with their different arguments .. Instead of declare them as follows:

```
obj1 = MyClass('object1','Tom',10)
obj2 = MyClass('object2','John',13)

.
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John',13]}
>>> instances = []
>>> for name, args in objects.items():
        inst = MyClass(*args)
        instances.append(inst)
```

Or directly:

```
>>> [MyClass(*args) for name, args in objects.items()]
[<MyClass: object1, Tom, 10>, <MyClass: object2, John, 13>]
```

or even simpler, ignoring names:

```
>>> [MyClass(*args) for args in objects.values()]
[<MyClass: object1, Tom, 10>, <MyClass: object2, John, 13>]
```

or returning a dictionary (works in Python 2.7+)

```
>>> {name: MyClass(*args) for name, args in objects.items()}
{'obj1': <MyClass: object1, Tom, 10>, 'obj2': <MyClass: object2, John, 13>}
```

This would even work if you have dynamic number of arguments for creating your instances (assuming your class constructor can handle this variable number - using defaults)

Using `itertools.starmap`

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(MyClass, objects.values())
[<MyClass: object1, Tom, 10>, <MyClass: object2, John, 13>]
```

Comment: If the name from the file is at all important, I'd use a dictionary instead of a list: `instances = { name: MyClass(*args) for name, args in objects.items()}`

Comment: no need for `name`: `MyClass(*args) for args in object.values()` in your last one-liner

Comment: many thanks !! this works like a charm.... and what if I want to sends one of the object as an argument for the other.. e.g.: in the normal coding I write .... obj1 = MyClass('object1','Tom',10)
obj2 = MyClass('object2','John',obj1)... how can i refer to it here ?

Answer (score 2):

```
objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John',13]}
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, *args):
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = var2
    self.var3 = var3

for i in objects.keys():
  my_class = MyClass(*objects[i])
  print my_class.__dict__

{'var1': 'object1', 'var3': 10, 'var2': 'Tom'}
{'var1': 'object2', 'var3': 13, 'var2': 'John'}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is create a list containing all of your new `MyClass` objects, like so:

```
class_objects = []
for o in objects.values():
    class_objects.append(MyClass(o[0], o[1], o[2]))
```

This makes a list called `class_objects` that contains all of your `MyClass` objects from the file.