# sending one object as an argument for another when using dictionaries keys as objects

Tags: python

This is actually related to a previous question that I have asked about here:[create multiple objects of a class with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191981/create-multiple-objects-of-a-class-with-different-arguments)

I want to know if there is a way to send one of the objects as an argument for another when using dictionaries keys as objects.. e.g.:

```
objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John',13]}
dic={name: MyClass(*args) for name, args in objects.items()}
```

in the normal coding I would write ....

```
obj1 = MyClass('object1','Tom',10) 
obj2 = MyClass('object2','John',obj1)
```

but with the following structure, it doesn't accept passing the object obj1:

```
objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John',obj1]}
dic={name: MyClass(*args) for name, args in objects.items()}
```

where it gives (NameError: global name 'obj1' is not defined):
so how can i do this when using dictionary keys as an objects in a right way?

**updated**.. error message has been added.

Comment: the title is terribly confusing...

Comment: In what way does it not accept it?

Comment: So what goes wrong? What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Indeed, this is not clear at all. Syntactically there is no reason this shouldn't work. So the problem must be in your ``MyClass`` implementation.

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* with all lines intact

Answer (score 0):

`objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John',obj1]}` this wont work  ever

however you could do something like

```
objects={'obj1':['object1','Tom',10],'obj2':['object2','John','obj1']}
fetch_ob = lambda x:objects.get(x,x)
dic = {name:MyClass(*list(map(fetch_ob,args))) for name,args in objects.items()}
```

but its kind of gross