# Is it possible for an instance of a class within a different class to inherit its variables

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, python-class

I have 2 classes, one does calculations `calc` and the other sets up and runs `setuprun` the calculation.

I have multiple instances of the `calc` class in `setuprun` to run multiple calculations in one go for each `tab`. [method from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598872/how-to-create-multiple-class-objects-with-a-loop-in-python)

At the moment they are separate classes but I'd like to inherit variables from `setuprun` to `calc`, specifically `excelbook` and `cases`, to remove some duplicated code. I have tried various combinations of parent, child and super with no luck.

I guess my question is; is it possible for an instance of a class within a different class to inherit its variables - as i write this, my feeling is not...

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks.

code below:

```
class calc():

    def __init__(self, excelbook, tab, cases):
        self.excelbook = excelbook
        self.cases = cases
        self.tab = tab

    def run(self):
        print(self.excelbook, self.cases, self.tab)


class setuprun():

    def __init__(self, excelbook, cases):
        self.excelbook = excelbook
        self.gettabs()
        runs = [calc(excelbook, t, cases) for t in self.tabs]
        for run in range(len(runs)):
            runs[run].run()
        self.check = runs

    def gettabs(self):
        self.tabs = list(self.excelbook)
```

can run with:

```
a = setuprun('xlsx', 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As i write this, my feeling is not...* **Do not underestimate Python ;)**

There is something strange about your code that I don't understand: you are taking the length of the string 'xlsx' to instantiate the calc classes. It just prints

```
xlsx 100 x
xlsx 100 l
xlsx 100 s
xlsx 100 x
```

That's fine with me though, but probably not correct in your final application.

After you instantiate the class `setuprun`, it instantiates 4x a class `calc()` each time with the same values for `excelbook` and `cases`. These two variables are instance variables of the class `setuprun`.

What you can do is turn them into *class* variables. After that, you can reference them directly, hence, you do not need to instantiate class `calc` with the common variables.

Because it is good practice to use capitalized names for classes (to distinguish them from instance variables) I do so in the adapted code below:

```
class Calc():

    def __init__(self, tab):
        self.excelbook = Setuprun.excelbook
        self.cases = Setuprun.cases
        self.tab = tab

    def run(self):
        print(self.excelbook, self.cases, self.tab)

class Setuprun():

    def __init__(self, excelbook, cases):
        Setuprun.excelbook = excelbook
        Setuprun.cases = cases
        self.gettabs()
        runs = [Calc(t) for t in self.tabs]
        for run in range(len(runs)):
            runs[run].run()
        self.check = runs

    def gettabs(self):
        self.tabs = list(self.excelbook)
        
a = Setuprun('xlsx', 100)
```

I'm not quite sure if this is what you were looking for, but I do hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was trying to do, was getting tangled up with super().__init__(). Didn't realise you could call variables from another Class directly. The strange thing was just to replicate a function in the code but didn't really change anything.

Comment: I can understand, once you're looking for the answer in a certain direction, it is sometimes hard to see the other possibilities. Glad it helped!