# For loop variable classes

Tags: python

How can I make it work so the i in the for loop can be added to sq_i. So I can create multiple objects called sq_1, sq_2, sq_3, etc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY7Hx.png)

Comment: Maybe the most natural way to do what you want is to create a dictionary? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Please post code as **text**, not as an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multiple class objects with a loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598872/how-to-create-multiple-class-objects-with-a-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be putting all those object in a dictionary:

```
class Board:
    SQUARES = {}
    def __init__(self, squares):
        self.squares = squares
        for i in range(self.squares):
            Board.SQUARES[f'sq_{i}'] = Square(i+1)
```

I don't think playing with `globals()` is a good idea - I mean, like this:

```
for i in range(self.squares):
    globals()[f'sq_{i}'] = Square(i+1)
```

What if the same global variable is defined somewhere else in your code, for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just naming them `sq_i` where `i` is some integer, it sounds like you want a list.

```py
class Board
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self.squares = [Square(i+1) for i in range(size)]
```

Now reference with:

```py
board = Board(16)
board.squares[0]  # first square
board.squares[2]  # third square
# etc...
```