# How do I dynamically create new objects that are members of another object in Python?

Tags: python, object, dynamic, composition

I'm attempting to create an "inn" object and dynamically create "customer" objects that come and go in a simulation game.

I've heard of composition, and the examples of composition I've been given are things like a car. The car "has an" engine object. It "has" four tire objects. So I can wrap my head around "has a" relationships.

My inn has a maximum number of customers it can hold (until the player buys more space for the inn) so I want to generate an arbitrary number of customers to populate it. The customer objects have things like customer names, customer experience points, customer gold held, etc.

The customers (who, when they exit the inn become "adventurers") will come and go depending on their survival in their adventures.

What I'm struggling with is how to dynamically create a customer and add it to the inn.

I've put both classes into the same file below and commented out the parts I tried (creating an iterator, creating objects in a loop inside the inn class, creating objects in a loop in main to test)

```
import random

class Actor:
    def __init__(self, name = "", hitPoints = 0, damage = 0, initiative = 0, experience = 0, wealth = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.hitPoints = hitPoints
        self.damage = damage
        self.initiative = initiative
        self.experience = experience
        self.wealth = wealth

    # def __iter__(self):
    #     self.index = 0
    #     return self

    # def __next__(self):
    #     self.index += 1
    #     return self

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def setHP(self, hitPoints):
        self.hitPoints = hitPoints
    def getHP(self):
        return self.hitPoints

    def setDmg(self, damage):
        self.damage = damage
    def getDmg(self):
        return self.damage

    def setInit(self, initiative):
        self.initiative = initiative
    def getInit(self):
        return self.initiative

    def setExp(self, experience):
        self.experience = experience
    def getExp(self):
        return self.experience

    def setWealth(self, wealth):
        self.wealth = wealth
    def getWealth(self):
        return self.wealth

    def printActor(self):
        print("Name = " + self.getName())
        print("HP   = " + str(self.getHP()))
        print("Dmg  = " + str(self.getDmg()))
        print("Init = " + str(self.getInit()))
        print("Exp  = " + str(self.getExp()))
        print("Gold = " + str(self.getWealth()))

class Inn:
    def __init__(self, owner, customerMax, wealth):
        self.owner = owner
        self.customerMax = customerMax
        self.wealth = wealth
        # self.customer = Actor()
        # self.customerLedger = [Actor()]

    def setOwner(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner
    def getOwner(self):
        return self.owner

    def setCustomerMax(self, customerMax):
        self.customerMax = customerMax
    def getCustomerMax(self):
        return self.customerMax

    def setWealth(self, wealth):
        self.wealth = wealth
    def getWealth(self):
        return self.wealth

    def addCustomer(self, customer):
        self.customerLedger = customer

    def printInn(self):
        print("Owner = " + self.getOwner())
        print("Max Customers = " + str(self.getCustomerMax()))
        print("Cash on Hand = " + str(self.getWealth()) + "\n")
        print("Customers:")
        # for self.customer in self.customerLedger:
        #     self.customer.printActor()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(r"assets/text/names", "r") as merDeNoms:
        name = merDeNoms.read().split()

    inn = Inn("Destro",4,5000)

    # customerLedger = [Actor() for x in range(inn.getCustomerMax())]
    # for x in customerLedger:
    #     player = x(random.choice(name), random.randint(30, 50), random.randint(5, 10), random.randint(5, 10), 0, random.randint(10, 100))
    #     inn.addCustomer(player)

    inn.printInn()
```

I've tried searching for creating dynamic objects, but search engines assume I either want to dynamically add attributes to existing objects, or dynamically define objects, or things around the problem I'm looking for. The ideas of creating objects in lists or dictionaries I picked up from [How to create multiple class objects with a loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598872/how-to-create-multiple-class-objects-with-a-loop-in-python) but I've had not much luck.

Comment: It seems like you want the Inn to contain a _list_ of customers, not just one.

Comment: Ahhhh. And if I'm looking at this right, lists can contain arbitrary items... including objects.

Thank you!