# How to make instances automatic in python

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

I want to make a new member of my class when a person sign up  but it's hard to do that manually

```
class user:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
user1=user('ali')
user2=user('reza')
user3=user('danial')
```

I want that when I get a  name input (and other information) it automatically generates a new user like this:

```
while True:
    'user+{number}'=user(input ('enter your name:'))
    number +=1
```

How to make this work

Comment: Don't, use a container such as a list or dictionary

Comment: Also related: [How to create multiple class objects with a loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21598872/2745495)